# What is meant by this "pair"?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm reading Angus Taylor's *General Theory of Functions and Integration* and I'm just slightly confused by some wording. In describing what is meant by a section in the real number field, it says to let all members of $F$ be put into two sections $L$ and $R$ in such a way that neither collection is void. Then the pair $(L,R)$ is a section of $F$. So when he refers to this "pair" he is basically saying a pair of sets of elements? Maybe my wording is a little off, but does my question make sense? If not I will try to elaborate.

Comment: Yes, it’s an ordered pair of sets of reals, but I suspect that there are additional conditions on $L$ and $R$ besides the ones that you’ve stated here.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes there are other conditions for the example, but I understood them and didn't need clairification. It was just that one part. Thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome.